# run Service even if android app is closed

Tags: java, android, service

My task is to run service even if app is closed.

My service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        AudioManager am;
        am= (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if(am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            else
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        Minute minute = new Minute();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarms ;
        Intent activate = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, activate, 0);
        alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute.minute);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "checkOnStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

In my activity:

```
Intent activate = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(activate);
```

i try to use foreground Service it's doesnt help me
But when I kill the app the service closed, what should I do to keep the service running after the app is killed?

Comment: Is this the whole service code? The start method is executed and then it returns... I can not see why it it should be keep alive. It seems that it ended because it has complete his tasks...

Comment: but i return Service.START_STICKY

Comment: You're right. Process should be restarted. Also, you implemented onStartCommand(), so, you is responsible to stop the service (and not the system). Anyway, could you please share whole code? And how you detect that service was destroyed? I have service as well.. in my case, I have some Broadcast receiver and they remain receiving messages even after Main Thread is destroyed... Share whole code or explain what you are trying to do in this service... I saw that you started an alarm manager..

Comment: I got your code. Your Pending Intent should start the service again, right?via PendingIntent.getService()

Comment: i try to turn on silent or ringer mode in cpecific time every day, time i take from another class, and this service must work allways